# Find the cell location of the text box

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a text box using the following VBA function:

```
Function DrawPostIt(Left As Single, Top As Single, Width As Single, _
    Height As Single, Text As String) As String
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left, _
        Top, Width, Height).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 192, 0) ' Yellow post-it
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    DrawPostIt = "BottomRightCell"
End Function
```

Now I would like to identify the cell location where excel drew the text box. I specifically need the cell location of the lower right corner. The objective is that `DrawPostIt()` function will return the cell position/location.

**Note:** Here I have found how to put a text box indicating the position based on the given cell  ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66934/how-do-you-place-a-textbox-object-over-a-specific-cell-when-automating-excel)), but that is not exactly what I want because I don't know upfront the cell location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
Sub CallTheFunction()
Dim Cell As Range
Set Cell = DrawPostIt(100, 150, 250, 150, "MyTextBox1")
MsgBox Cell.Address
End Sub

Function DrawPostIt(Left As Single, Top As Single, Width As Single, _
    Height As Single, Text As String) As Range
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left, _
        Top, Width, Height).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 192, 0) ' Yellow post-it
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = Text
    Set DrawPostIt = Selection.BottomRightCell
End Function
```

If you want to draw it in specific prior known cell, you may try this...

```
Sub CallTheFunction2()
Dim Cell As Range

Set Cell = Range("D5")  'Here you can defind the cell

DrawPostIt2 Cell.Left, Cell.Top, 200, 100, "MyTextBox2"
End Sub

Function DrawPostIt2(Left As Single, Top As Single, Width As Single, _
    Height As Single, Text As String)
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left, _
        Top, Width, Height).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 192, 0) ' Yellow post-it
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = Text
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works as expected just with simple copy and paste.

Comment: You're welcome David! Glad it worked as expected. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BottomRightCell` property of `Shape` object.

```
Selection.BottomRightCell.Address
```

It's better to set a reference to your text box than using `Selection`. Something like this:

```
Dim box as Shape
Set box = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left, _
        Top, Width, Height)
With box.ShapeRange.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 192, 0) ' Yellow post-it
    .Transparency = 0
    .Solid
End With
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce your solution, but I am getting an error: *"438-Object doesn't support this property or method"*. At the line `With box...`. I modified the question to wrap the solution into a function, the idea is to return the bottom right cell position. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

please try this

run *testMe* sub

```
Function drawPostIt(Left As Single, Top As Single, Width As Single, Height As Single, Text As String) As Range

    Dim aaa As Shape
    Set aaa = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left, Top, Width, Height)

    aaa.Title = "my fancy yellow post-it"
    aaa.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = Text
    aaa.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
    aaa.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 192, 0) ' Yellow post-it ... lol ... orange
    aaa.Fill.Transparency = 0
    aaa.Fill.Solid

'   aaa.TopLeftCell.Select                ' these two lines are for testing
'   aaa.BottomRightCell.Select            ' this is the range of interest

    Set drawPostIt = aaa.BottomRightCell

'   aaa.Delete                             ' for testing

End Function

Sub testMe()

    ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Select         ' move selection box out of the way (not needed though)

    Dim bottomRight As Range
    Set bottomRight = drawPostIt(50, 90, 120, 70, "message on postit")    ' drawPostIt() returns a range object

    bottomRight.Select                      ' drawPostIt() returns a range object

End Sub
```

Comment: Thx, I selected the @sktneer answer because it works directly without modification, the idea is the same as yours, but I was not able to reproduce yours, probably some minor stuff.